# spring data redis cyclic reference

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data

Hi I am new to spring data redis, and am having below circular reference issue:
say i have code in java that looks like:

```html
class Person{

  @Id
  private String Id;
  private String name;
  private int age;
  @Reference
  private Person father;
  @Reference
  private List<Person> children;

... setters and getters
}
```

**my goal is that when a person's name is given, i want to get a person object that has his father information and children information, by information I mean person object.**

the issue i am seeing is there's a circular reference going on here as the person whose name is given is included in his father's children list so it actually reference himself hence formed a circle.

my question is what is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Are you sure @Id is prepended to 'private String name'?

Comment: @BishwajitPurkaystha the post in code is not real code, just to explain the idea.... let me update that and change it to Id.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with how Spring-data-Redis works

@Reference here is loaded eagerly (there is no lazy loading available in Spring-Data-Redis yet), so when you insert father's children then you will face circular dependency as Child will have Father and this Father will have Same child which is having Same father ....and so on. Below is a better picture

```
Person
{
    name: Rob,
    father: ...
    childrens: [ {
        Person{
            name: Sam
            father: [ {
                Person
                {
                    name: Rob,
                    father: ...
                    childrens: [ {
                        Person{
                            name: Sam
                            father: [ {
                            ............
                            ..................
                            ......................
                            ............................
                            Repeating this relation...

                            }]

                        }
                    } ]
                }

            }]

        }
    } ]
}
```

This will create circular dependencies as Java will keep mapping the father child relation recursively resulting in memory overflow, this is exactly what you should avoid here.

**Solution:**

Ditch the @Reference and keep the Id for father and son, something like shown below

```
class Person{

  @Id
  private String Id;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  private String fatherId;

  private List<String> childrensIds;

... setters and getters
}
```

And the modify the DAO layer to fetch Father and Children separately and attach in response.

Redis or most other non-relational databases are not designed to hold relation (as name suggests), and @Reference should only be used with the fields having one-way mapping that too if necessary.